Object type that has properties of type x in .d.ts files
I want to describe a JavaScript type in a .d.ts file - object with all properties of type string (basically the same as string[] but with an object).
Example object:
const myObject = {
    a: "someString",
    b: "otherString",
    c: "lorem ipsum",
    d: ""
}

Types:
declare const myObject: Object<string>

I tried things like Object<string> and Object<string,string> but none of them worked and VSCode hover menus in the declaration file kept saying const myObject: any.
How do I make the type work properly?
It doesn't matter if I would have to define an interface or somenthing else to make it work.
